# Handling STDIN/STDOUT with perl's Net::Server

Tags: perl, stdout, stdin

I am trying to build a perl based server that will accept incoming requests and, based on that request, read/write data to server's STDIN/OUT. So I need to accept data from the client STDIN, write it to the server's STDIN (where it is handled by another process), capture the results of that request from the server's STDOUT and then ship it to the client.

I was hoping to build this off of Net::Server but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to direct data specifically to the server's STDIN. In my ideal world I'd have a set of file handles like CLISTDIN, CLISTDOUT, SRVSTDIN, and SRVSTDOUT that I could discretely address and manage. I'm just at a loss of how to go about it in Net::Server.

I don't have to use Net::Server so other suggestions are welcome. Net::Server just has a number of other features I would like to use.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What are your clients going to be (and how will they connect)? Terminal, or software (and what tools will you use to write them)?

Comment: The clients just write to server (print if connected via `telnet`, or print to socket obtained when connecting via `IO::Socket::INET`) and that comes on the server's `STDIN`. There is nothing to do for that, just write from a client.  Try: copy paste the few lines from synopsis for the server, start it, and then connect to it with `telnet` (or copy paste code for a basic client from somewhere using `IO::Socket::INET`), and print. Note that for asynchronous handling you need to use a 'personality' to set up the server.

Comment: What do you want those ("ideal-world" :) filehandles for?  That's all there.

Comment: This is an interface the to the ExaBGP service. ExaBGP can be configured to accept commands via an external handler that write these commands to STDOUT. A few people have developed a RESTful API but the level of security with this is somewhat lacking. As such, I'm rolling my own that incorporates PFS via signed Diffie Hellman keys.

Comment: Sounds great. But it's not clear (to me) how that brings up a problem with the server's `STDIN`? It appears clear that you know full well how all this works in principle, so the question is probably far more involved. (Your server will be an intermediary that forms input for the service, I guess with its own input from its clients, and prints it to the service?) Perhaps provide more detail (or add more specific terms to the title or tags to the question, starting with "_ExaBGP_")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I could do this by overloading post_accept to change how STDIN/STDOUT were being used. I was able to create two distinct filehandles so I could refer to the client IN/OUT without breaking the servers IO. That said, Net::Server kept getting in the way of what IO wanted to do so I abandoned it and just rolled my own forking server. Ended up being easier overall.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about just using `ssh`? With ssh your can run commands on a remote computer (server) which redirects your stdin to that command, and the stdout from that command to yours. Simple demo:

```
$ echo "hello, world" | md5sum
22c3683b094136c3398391ae71b20f04  -

$ echo "hello, world" | ssh myserver.com md5sum
22c3683b094136c3398391ae71b20f04  -
```

Or

```
$ echo "hello, world" | ssh user@myserver.com "/path/any/command --with --args x y z"
```

(You can set up ssh for automatic login with ip check by `ssh-keygen` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` wont say more about that here)

Comment: I thought about this using public keys. However, this is going to be an interface to ExaBGP and I'm not sure if there is a good way turn sshd into a valid interface for ExaBGP (largely because of how sshd forks a child). RESTful APIs could work but they don't really have the level of security I'd like for critical infrastructure that could bring down a regional network if it's compromised in anyway. I'm more than open to suggestions though.